# bash script result a syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I am trying to script my SCREEN access and automate as much as possible my connection to my bastion host.

here my bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# set TERM to xterm-256color
export TERM=xterm-256color
# here we source bashrc
. .bashrc

# Detecting Command Line Arguments
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    # check if the screen argument exist
    if ! screen -list | grep -q "$1"; then
        # create screen with new argument
        screen -S $1
    # At this point, argument is not found on screen
    else
        # Create it with argument specified.
        screen -x $1
# Detecting if default screen exist
elif [[ ! screen -list | grep -q "myscreen" ]]; then
    # no default screen exist, Create it !
    screen -S myscreen
else
    # attache to the default screen
    screen -x myscreen
fi
```

there the output:

```
$ ./myscreen.sh test123
./myscreen.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
./myscreen.sh: line 18: `elif ! screen -list | grep -q "myscreen" ; then'
```

I tried also to `[[ ! EXPR ]]` no much better.

any one have a idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed your script and saw that it is missing a `fi` before the elif.  Of course, I write bash code everyday, so this was easy for me to spot.  You can use a bash syntax checker to help review your scripts (www.shellcheck.net).

Here's the results provided by that site:

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 8:
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
                   ^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this then clause.

Line 10:
    if ! screen -list | grep -q "$1"; then
    ^-- SC1046: Couldn't find 'fi' for this 'if'.
    ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this if expression. Fix to allow more checks.

Line 18:
elif [[ ! screen -list | grep -q "myscreen" ]]; then
^-- SC1047: Expected 'fi' matching previously mentioned 'if'.
     ^-- SC1072: Unexpected keyword/token. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.

$
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re missing a fi statement to close out your internal if-else:

```
if 
    if 
        ...
    else 
        ...
    fi  # You were missing this line
elif 
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```